# Is there a way to import/ export data from one project to another project in the portal?

Tags: microsoft-translator

I want to export the uploaded data (parallel translations) to another project to use as model training, but is unable to find how

-Tried searching on stack overflow and FAQs

Answer (score 0):

All projects within the same workspace share the same data store. You can reuse the data in another project, as long as the language pairs of the original project and the new project are the same. 
To move data to another workspace, you will need to download first, then upload to the new workspace.